# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jeditable, autogrow

I'm using `Jeditable` plugin of [Mika Tuupola](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/4/autogrow-textarea-for-jeditable) with autogrowing. I've followed his indications but the console shows this error:

[image]

I'm using Symfony2 with `fosjsroutingbundle`; this is the reason for use the variable of editable. This works fine.

This is the JS code:

```
 $('.editarContenido').editable(Routing.generate('criContenido_ajax.' + $('html').attr('lang'), { "_locale": $('html').attr('lang'), "pysStr": $('section').attr('pelicula') }),
        { 
            type      : "autogrow",
            submit    : 'OK',
            indicator : 'Saving...',
            tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
            autogrow : {
                lineHeight : 16,
                maxHeight  : 512
            }
        });

        $.editable.addInputType('autogrow', {
            element : function(settings, original) {
                var textarea = $('<textarea>');
                if (settings.rows) {
                    textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
                } else {
                    textarea.height(settings.height);
                }
                if (settings.cols) {
                    textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
                } else {
                    textarea.width(settings.width);
                }
                $(this).append(textarea);
                return(textarea);
            },
            plugin : function(settings, original) {
                $('textarea', this).autogrow(settings.autogrow);
            }
        });
```

## EDIT

[image]

Comment: That error message image is practically unreadable. Could you replace it with a cut-and-paste of the text?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you do not have jQuery in place or it is placed in the HTML document after the jEditable plugin.

Make sure your scripts tags are sorted just like in the source code of this page:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html and all of them are properly loading.

Edit: regarding your new error: you will have to use an older version of jQuery than 1.9, as browser detection was removed beginning with that version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because I had applied 'async' to the  tag.  I remove async and everything worked fine.